# Scala Breeze Beta distribution parameter estimation

Tags: scala

I am trying to fit my data(a list of CTR(double) values) to a beta distribution and estimate the alpha and beta shape parameters. I found I can do so using breeza library's mle method, but I do not understand the arguments required to call the mle method:-

```
object Beta extends ExponentialFamily[Beta,Double] with ContinuousDistributionUFuncProvider[Double,Beta] {
  type Parameter = (Double,Double)
  case class SufficientStatistic(n: Double, meanLog: Double, meanLog1M: Double) extends distributions.SufficientStatistic[SufficientStatistic]  {
    def *(weight: Double) = SufficientStatistic(n*weight,meanLog, meanLog1M)
    def +(t: SufficientStatistic) = {
      val delta = t.meanLog - meanLog
      val newMeanLog = meanLog + delta * (t.n /(t.n + n))
      val logDelta = t.meanLog1M - meanLog1M
      val newMeanLog1M = meanLog1M + logDelta * (t.n /(t.n + n))
      SufficientStatistic(n+t.n, newMeanLog, newMeanLog1M)
    }
  }
```

what is `n`, `meanLog` and `meanLog1`?

Answer (score 0):

Those are sufficient statistics. In an exponential family, the maximum likelihood estimator depends on the data only through the empirical average of the sufficient statistics. For the beta family, the sufficient statistics are `log(x)` and `log(1-x)`.  `meanLog` and `meanLog1` are the sample averages of `log(x)` and `log(1-x)`. `n` is the sample size, and it does not enter the MLE estimation directly. It is used in the package to combine two sets of sufficient statistics.

Comment: is there other ways to use the beta MLE method.

Comment: is there other ways to use the beta MLE method. For example? `private Tuple2<Object, Object> getBetaPriorParameters(List<Double> ctrs) {
        Beta.SufficientStatistic sufficientStatistic = Beta.emptySufficientStatistic();
        for (Double ctr : ctrs) {
            sufficientStatistic = sufficientStatistic.$plus(Beta.sufficientStatisticFor(ctr));
        }
        return  Beta.mle(sufficientStatistic);
    }`

Comment: Seems that you are adding the aggregation into the mle method. That should be fine, but can be achieved by aggregating first, and then pass them Beta.mle(Beta.SufficientStatistic(1, meanLog, meanLog1m))

Comment: can you please help me with exact code? i don't have enough experience with scala